# EditText views don't receive string data from intent on android 2.3

Tags: android, android-intent, android-edittext

The following code works on an emulator set to a recent (4..) android version, but not on a real Galaxy I running android 2.3.
how can I make my app work on the older version too?

```
    Intent callingIntent = getIntent();
    //check if it was an Edit/GetContent action
            if (callingIntent.getAction() == Intent.ACTION_EDIT){

                EditText editSubject = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                EditText editBody = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

                //get data:

                String body = callingIntent.getStringExtra("body");
                String subject = callingIntent.getStringExtra("subject");
                //show data:
                editSubject.setText(subject);
                editBody.setText(body);

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a simple thing really, but can be tricky to find... had the same thing.

Intent Actions are actually String.
For example:
`Intent.ACTION_EDIT = "android.intent.action.EDIT"`
`Intent.ACTION_VIEW = "android.intent.action.VIEW"`
etc.

In java Strings must be compared using
`someText.equals(someOtherText)` 
and not 
`(someText == someOtherText)`

(Same goes for any other object really, the == operator only works for primitives - int,float,bool etc.)

The == operator can work sometimes on strings and sometimes not,
so it's a very annoying bug to find...

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be that at some point in the code, you're using a method that isn't supported at the Android 2.3 API level (most likely API level 10), but the code you've posted looks good.  Plus the program would most likely crash in that scenario and you'd have an error log to help find the problem.

What info do the 'body' and 'subject' strings contain after getting the intent extras when running on 2.3?  Perhaps post the code that is populating the extras of the intent as well?